# PHP Error Checking for PDO Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My code is:

```
//insert a new record
$sSQL="INSERT INTO store_content_charity (store_id, description, dateaddedserial, approvalstatus) VALUES (:store_id, :description, :dateaddedserial, 0) ";
$objQuery=$objConn->prepare($sSQL);
if (false===$objQuery)
    echo 'prepare() failed: ' . $objConn->error . '<br/>';

if (!$objQuery->bindParam(':store_id', $_SESSION['StoreLoggedIn_ID']))
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $objQuery->errno . ") " . $objQuery->error . '<br/>';
if (!$objQuery->bindParam(':description', trim($_POST["txtDescription"])))
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $objQuery->errno . ") " . $objQuery->error . '<br/>';
if (!$objQuery->bindParam(':dateaddedserial', date("YmdHis")))
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $objQuery->errno . ") " . $objQuery->error . '<br/>';

if (!$objQuery->execute())
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $objQuery->errno . ") " . $objQuery->error . '<br/>';
```

It fails the import, with the message "Execute failed: () " - that's it... no number or message.

1. Does anyone know why it's failing?
2. Why am I not getting an error message that will tell me why it's failing?

What's odd, is that I know this code does work if I remove the bindParam and hard code the data...

Thanks, as always, for your advice...

Edit:
I've added the line suggested by Mike B below & even surrounded it with a try/catch:

```
try {
    $objConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

But this just causes the script to fail, without any message, at this line...

Comment: Turn on exceptions in PDO http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php `$objConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Try using `$objQuery->errorCode()` in place of `$objQuery->errno`. Also `$objQuery->errorInfo()` will give you an array with different information.

Comment: In addition, try wrapping everything in a try-catch; if I'm reading Mike's suggestion correctly, the script will throw an exception when there's an error (and it's not being caught)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike B & ChrisForrence....

Once I'd surrounded everything in a try-catch, I could see the error & was able to fix it.

(The error was that the file was encoded as UTF-8 without BOM and the text I was trying to add included the £ symbol - when I encoded as UTF-8, everything works as expected!)

I guess I can modify the code to:

```
$objConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    $sSQL="INSERT INTO store_content_charity (store_id, description, dateaddedserial, approvalstatus) VALUES (:store_id, :description, :dateaddedserial, 0) ";
    $objQuery=$objConn->prepare($sSQL);
    $objQuery->bindParam(':store_id', $_SESSION['StoreLoggedIn_ID']);
    $objQuery->bindParam(':description', trim($_POST["txtDescription"]));
    $objQuery->bindParam(':dateaddedserial', date("YmdHis"));
    $objQuery->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```